# Is there a way to download a font in HTML5 pages before rendering the page?

Tags: css, font-face

While using @font-face HTML5/CSS3 loads the page, and you slowly see the fonts appear. Is there no way to load the fonts first?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is. You might be able to do some fiddling with jQuery to make it only display content once the CSS and fonts are loaded, but I've not done this myself.

BTW @font-face has nothing to do with HTML5, it's part of CSS3, although it was part of CSS2, but was removed from CSS2.1.

Answer (score 4):

You might get some luck (especially in the future) with [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/link_prefetching_faq):

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="pathto/font">
```

(only supported by Firefox, at the moment). If you use this on a page *before* the page where `@font-face` is used, the font file can be in the cache before it is actually used.

Comment: Interesting. This is the behavior I would like my page to exhibit. Unfortunately, browser compatibility for various new HTML5 features is fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a draft for [preload](https://w3c.github.io/preload/) which is going to be released with [Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload?hl=en).

With this feature we should be able to do this in the head element and probably flush it before the rest of the html is rendered and sent to the browser

```
<link rel=preload as=font href=...>
```